# Location information is not shown in "Years" view of Photos App

Tags: macos, ios, icloud, photos, gps

I do not see the location information of the pictures I have taken in 2014 when I am in "**Years**" view.

[image: Years view]

I am sure pictures have GPS information on them. If I go in to **2014** year, I can see that pictures have location information.

[image: 2014 view]

Has anyone had this problem?

Notes:

- This has been going on since iOS 7 and I started using iOS 7 when it was beta.
- It is not that I have been to many places in 2014. In that case it should have said "United States, Canada & 4 more" (something like that)
- I called apple support but they couldn't help.
- I have the same problem on both iOS Photos app and Mac Photos app. For this reason, I have sent Mac Photos app diagnostic information to apple as a bug report but no luck there either.
- I have reset and restored my phone, and iCloud pictures and no luck.
- I have iCloud Photo Library on.

Comment: I have gotten in touch with apple support (Emma Andersson | Senior Technical Advisor). She sounded very professional and listened my problem very carefully. She has advised me to reset my phone (even though I had tried it before). She told me she will get in touch with me but I have not heard anything from her. She doesn't reply my emails. I feel like it was just a waste of time and this is not how I know Apple.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is probably down to visiting lots of countries maybe?
For example, I have currently visited 7 countries this year (2018) and I am sure my info was there a month ago.
It seems to be a sequence as someone has mentioned already with ‘this country, this country & 3 others, where it doesn’t seem to mention 4 others or 5 others etc.
Another thing.... info does not show for me in 2015 either... that is the year I visited various Caribbean islands), so it’s probably a multi country thing.
Maybe there is something in that?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are not alone. I've been having the same problem, started mid-way through 2014. I didn't think anything of it at the time, but wish I had.

I've also gone through multiple rounds with Apple Support only for them to repeatedly tell me that I have no GPS data in 2014 pictures, despite the fact that the vast majority do have GPS data.

A few months ago the same thing happened to me with 2015, lost location information in 'Years' view. I realised this was related to importing a series of photos from my GoPro, and after deleting them all from my library, adjusting GPS EXIF data and re-importing (this was before Photos for Mac supported editing GPS data directly), the issue went away.

I suspect the issue is down to a selection of images that do not have GPS data / have invalid GPS data, causing something in Photos to barf.

Reading https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7174772?start=0&tstart=0 has led me to believe that it may be possible to create a smart album for all photos in 2014 that do not have GPS data. If so, then it can lead to one or more of the following options:

1. Export all untagged images, re-importing one at a time and identifying which image causes the library to stop summarising for the year
2. Identify a tipping point, if it's over a certain % of untagged images that causes the library to stop summarising for the year
3. Manually tag all the untagged images, where relevant, if it's a % issue.
4. Delete some images.

Sorry I don't have anything more helpful to report, but at least you know you're not alone! :-)

If you do make any progress on any of the above, please to share. I will also share if and when I'm able to identify anything further.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the reply. No luck on my side. Still...